# Insert video in README.md for an extension of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, readme

I have a video in .mp4 format and I want to insert it in README.md for an extension of vscode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  You'll need to convert it to an animated GIF and reference it just like the Debugger for Chrome Extension does: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you very much,where I must put the .gif file? (in the same folder of extension?)

Comment: Anywhere, as long as the img src references the correct location.  The sample folder as the extension seems like a good place.

Comment: I have installed my extension and I have .gif file in folder images. When I see the preview of my extension inside vscode I don't see the .gif. I use this tag in markdown <img src="images/bs.gif" />
If I use a .gif stored in http://g.recordit.co then I can see the .gif

Comment: I *think* `<img ...` tags in markdown are interpreted relative to the repository URL in your `package.json`, and you have to use HTTPS. Try using markdown syntax instead: `![](images/bs.gif)`

Comment: Actually it seems all images are relative to the repository URL. You can't bundle images with your extension at all. Kind of rubbish for private extensions.

Answer (score 2):

That should be possible with VSCode 1.78 (Apr. 2023), since:

- [issue 177820](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177820): <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `mp4` into markdown should insert `<video>` tag
- [PR 179489](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/179489): Insert `<video>` tag for `shift+mp4` into `.md`

It is available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), and works for `.ogg` files too.